# On IISNODE, nodejs application cann't connect to DB recycle or inactive process shutdown

Tags: node.js, iisnode, node-oracledb

For some reason which I do not know why node application is not able to reconnect DB after recycle. the connection can be done after IISNode application manual restart. Below is my server.js file which did not find anything wrong in it;

```
const http = require('http');
var openHttpConnections = {};
var httpServer;
const dbOperationsWPool = require('./api/dbLib/dbOperationsWPool');

const compression = require('compression');
const helmet = require('helmet')
require('dotenv').config({
    path: __dirname + '\\mynode.env'
});
const dbPoolConfig = require("./dbPoolConfig");
const config = require('./config'); // get our config file
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    app = express();
// port = process.env.PORT || 4600;

const verifyToken = require('./api/lib/verifyToken');
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('superSecret', config.secret);

var authRoutes = require('./api/routes/authRoutes');
authRoutes(app); //register the route
var wsRoutes = require('./api/routes/wsRoutes');
wsRoutes(app);
// const wsVerifyToken = require('./api/lib/verifyWebServiceToken');
// app.use(wsVerifyToken);
app.use(verifyToken); // Yeri değiştirilmemeli. bu satırdan sonra oluşan routes token aranacaktır

const commonRoutes = require('./api/routes/commonRouter');
commonRoutes(app);
var izinRoutes = require('./api/routes/ikRoutes');
izinRoutes(app);

var satinalmaRoutes = require('./api/routes/satinalmaRoutes');
satinalmaRoutes(app);
var finansRoutes = require('./api/routes/finansRoutes');
finansRoutes(app);

var reportRoutes = require('./api/routes/reportRoutes');
reportRoutes(app);

app.use(handleError);
httpServer = http.Server(app);
app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.status(404).send({
        url: req.originalUrl + ' not found'
    })
});
httpServer.on('connection', function (conn) {
    var key = conn.remoteAddress + ':' + (conn.remotePort || '');
    openHttpConnections[key] = conn;
    conn.on('close', function () {
        delete openHttpConnections[key];
    });
});
httpServer.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log("Caught flash policy server socket error: ")
    console.log(err.stack)
});
/// create pool
dbOperationsWPool.createPool(dbPoolConfig).then(function () {
        // IS_NODE_PROD
        var port = 4900;
        if (process.env.IS_NODE_PROD === 'true' || process.env.IS_NODE_TEST === "true") {
            port = process.env.PORT;
        }

        httpServer.listen(port, function () {
            console.log('Webserver listening on localhost:' + port);
        });


    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error('Error occurred creating database connection pool', err);
        console.log('Exiting process');
        process.exit(0);
    });

//app.listen(port);
//console.log('Onay RESTful API server started on: //' + port);



function handleError(err, req, res, next) {
    //console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send({
        error: 'Hata oluştu Erp yardım masasına başvurunuz'
    });
    shutdown(); //process would usually be restarted via something like https://github.com/foreverjs/forever
}

function shutdown() {
    console.log('Shutting down');
    dbOperationsWPool.terminatePool()
        .then(function () {
            console.log('node-oracledb connection pool terminated');
            console.log('Exiting process');
            process.exit(0);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred while terminating node-oracledb connection pool', err);
            console.log('Exiting process');
            process.exit(0);
        });


    for (key in openHttpConnections) {
        openHttpConnections[key].destroy();
    }
}
```

the only line which might be suspicious is the shutdown function which termenates the pool. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add details about what is happening: errors, hangs, etc. and at what time they occur.  Show the tracing you have done to verify where the problem might be.

Comment: I have no Trace in hand the only thing is that I am not reaching the database also iis recycle. I need a request that ido not need the database can be processed on the iis after the recycle. But for some how I'm losing database connection